# Converting an array of objects into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, pup

I am trying to convert the "count" key from each object within the test array into a new array so I end up with something like

newCount =[0,0,0,0]

```
const test =  [
      {
        id: 0,
        count: 0,
        image: "",
        text: 'Some text about finn'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        count: 0,
        image: "",
        text: 'Some text about daphne'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        count: 0,
        image: "",
        text: 'Some text  finn'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        count: 0,
        image: "",
        text: 'Some text  daphne'
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` on your test array to extract the `count` property value of each object:

```
const newCount = test.map(t => t.count);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map on the array:

```
const newarray = test.map(item => item.count);
```

[Array map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)